# Unable to access JSONBin.io even I have added the Auth Headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, basically, I am trying to get data from **JSONbin.io**. I have set the RequestHeader before I send the request. As you see there's `beforeSend` and                 `xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Master-Key", "$2b$10$QCzFeVffyq7vaiSBUfPbCeXUGV.IBpiHlWIOsDQAgj########");`. But, it still say Error 401 aka unauthenticated request. I wondering if someone can help me with this. I also provide image that show that the headers is there.

Link: https://jsonbin.io/api-reference

Image: https://ibb.co/jGtFLk9

````
    <script>
      function getKey() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/624efc9cd8a4cc06909d66cd/2',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Master-Key", "$2b$10$QCzFeVffyq7vaiSBUfPbCeXUGV.IBpiHlWIOsDQAgj########");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                const keyStore = data.keys;
                var copyKey = document.getElementById("KeyDisplay");
                document.getElementById('KeyDisplay').value = keyStore[Math.floor(Math.random() * 49)]
                document.getElementById('Button').textContent = "Copied Key"
                document.getElementById("Button").disabled = true;
                copyKey.select();
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyKey.value);
            }
        });
      }
    </script>
    ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQxGv.png
````

Comment: https://jsonbin.io/api-reference/bins/create#request-headers says `Content-Type: application/json` is also a required header. (`dataType: "json"` does not cause that to be added - that is about the data type you expect to get back in the response.)

Comment: I want to read the bin not create a bin. https://jsonbin.io/api-reference/bins/read

Comment: So probably is no needed as I see.